# populate combobox editable human_name and line edit phone and email from mariadb

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, mariadb, qcombobox

I have table hr and 1 combobox with a list of hr, I want to show email and phone to `hremail_lineEdit` and `hrphone_lineEdit`, but I can only show phone to `hrphone_lineEdit`.

```
def hr_name(self):
    self._conn = pymysql.connect(host=127.0.0.1, port=3306, user='root', passwd=root, db='testhr', charset='utf8')
    self._cur = self._conn.cursor()
    sql_coop4hr = 'select human_name,email,phone from hr'
    count_coop4hr = self._cur.execute(sql_coop4hr)
    res_coop4hr = self._cur.fetchall()
    for row in res_coop4hr:
        un, email, phone = row
        self.hr_name_comboBox.addItem(un, email)

def hr_email(self):
    self.hremail_lineEdit.setText(self.hr_name_comboBox.currentData()) #email
    self.hrphone_lineEdit.setText(self.hr_name_comboBox.currentData()) #phone
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options:

- Pass email and phone as a tuple (or list) to the userData:

  ```py
  self.hr_name_comboBox.clear()
  for row in res_coop4hr:
      un, email, phone = row
      self.hr_name_comboBox.addItem(un, (email, phone))
  ```

  ```py
  def hr_email(self):
      email, phone = self.hr_name_comboBox.currentData()
      self.hremail_lineEdit.setText(email)
      self.hrphone_lineEdit.setText(phone)
  ```
- Create 2 roles associated with each data:

  ```py
  EMAIL_ROLE = Qt.UserRole
  PHONE_ROLE = Qt.UserRole + 1
  ```

  ```py
  self.hr_name_comboBox.clear()
  for i, row in enumerate(res_coop4hr):
      un, email, phone = row
      self.hr_name_comboBox.insertItem(i, un)
      self.hr_name_comboBox.setItemData(i, email, EMAIL_ROLE)
      self.hr_name_comboBox.setItemData(i, phone, PHONE_ROLE)
  ```

  ```py
  def hr_email(self):
      index = self.hr_name_comboBox.currentIndex()
      email = self.hr_name_comboBox.itemData(index, EMAIL_ROLE)
      phone = self.hr_name_comboBox.itemData(index, PHONE_ROLE)
      self.hremail_lineEdit.setText(email)
      self.hrphone_lineEdit.setText(phone)
  ```